# System.PlatformNotSupportedException when using mongodb driver on .net 5

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, blazor, webassembly

I have a `blazor wasm app` and I am trying to connect to a `mongodb`. As soon as I make a `FindAsync` or something that connects to the db, I get an exception that this is not supported on this platform. I google this and found some issues that had to do with the connectionstring, but in my integrationtests the same connectionstring works fine. The `MongoClient` is registered as singleton and I use `async await` everywhere as `wasm` does not seem to support `.Result` or any blocking calls. I am on a mac and develop with rider. I tried multiple ways to connect to the db, but I always get this cryptic error.

This is the stacktrace:

```
A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "157.90.1.251:3513" }", EndPoint: "157.90.1.251:3513", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
blazor.webassembly.js:1 ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Net.Sockets is not supported on this platform.
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateSocket(EndPoint endPoint)
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
blazor.webassembly.js:1   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-08-18T09:47:41.3960000Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-08-18T09:47:41.3960000Z" }] }.
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task completedTask)
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedAsync(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServerAsync(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAfterServerSelectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.StartImplicitSessionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<UsingImplicitSessionAsync>d__106`1[[FadingFlameLeague.UserAccounts.UserAccount, FadingFlameLeague, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[FadingFlameLeague.UserAccounts.UserAccount, FadingFlameLeague, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at FadingFlameLeague.Repositories.MongoDbRepositoryBase.<Upsert>d__9`1[[FadingFlameLeague.UserAccounts.UserAccount, FadingFlameLeague, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext() in /Users/simonheiss/IdeaProjects/FadingFlameLeague/FadingFlameLeague/Repositories/MongoDbRepositoryBase.cs:line 63
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at FadingFlameLeague.Pages.Register.OnValidSubmit() in /Users/simonheiss/IdeaProjects/FadingFlameLeague/FadingFlameLeague/Pages/Register.razor:line 55
```

this is how I generate the MongoClient

```
services.AddSingleton(_ =>
        {
            var mongoConnectionString = "mongodb://157.90.1.251:3513";
            return new MongoClient(mongoConnectionString);
        });
```

And something like that throws the exception:

```
private async Task OnValidSubmit()
{
    var mongoDatabase = client.GetDatabase("test");
    var mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<UserAccount>(typeof(UserAccount).Name);
    await mongoCollection.InsertOneAsync(new UserAccount());
}
```

This is really frustrating, it allready cost me a few hours and I just dont seem to find an issue. A few articles mentioned that wasm and .net standard dont work together well, and the mongoclient is in .net standard 2.1. But I can not imagine that this is an issue, I mean I am for sure not the first person to test wasm and mongo together ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is that you're trying to open a socket in a wasm runtime:

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Net.Sockets is not supported on this platform.
blazor.webassembly.js:1   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
```

You cannot open sockets in a web browser so you get `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

Similarly, I don't believe you would achieve the capability to work directly with a MongoDB database from a web browser, unless such interaction would be done through HTTP or websocket. I would expect you to require a special library for that.

I am not sure if having a web client connected directly to a database is a great idea either, from security perspective.

Comment: ok, then I think I misunderstood webassembly comletely. I thought it would work similar to a mvc app where I basically call a backend. Yes for sure, I dont want my connection string in the browser, of course. I will have to move to a server app, I guess. Thanks for the help!

Comment: In that case, you could also give Blazor server-side a shot.

Comment: jeah that is what i meant, i just ported the app and now it works fine. Definitely good to know that xD